# Where to add a semicolon in this rails line of code?

Tags: javascript

Code Climate says this line:

```
done = $(this).hasClass('done') ? 1 : 0
```

is missing a semicolon. 
Where should I add in this semicolon for it to be correct?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: That looks a lot like JavaScript. Are you sure this is Rails?

Comment: That is Javascript in which case the semicolon goes on the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semicolon goes at the end:

```
done = $(this).hasClass('done') ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw) - the semicolon goes on the end.

```
done = $(this).hasClass('done') ? 1 : 0;
```

is equivalent to

```
if $(this).hasClass('done')
    done = 1;
else
    done = 0;
```